# Is there something to make purchases in Amazon automatically like an API or something?

Tags: api, automation

I was wondering if you know asomething to purchase products automatically in Amazon, I'm using CasperJS but I would like something without being dependant of CasperJS or ZincAPI.

Do you know from where can I start ?

I  have been trying to automate everything with CasperJS and it works. But that is not the way that I want.

Comment: There's nothing unfortunately, nor does it seem amazon is interested in adding this. You can do it yourself with a JS platform, or pay the $1/order that zincapi (Currently) charges